# how detect result is from which table, when use select ... union ... in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT id FROM table2;" , $link);

    while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    echo $end['id']; // how separate and specify output is frow which table ?   
    }
```

i have two table (phpmyadmin), and i want to search in both of them with 1qeury, then i'm use UNION to combine, now i want to seprating output and specify from what table is evry result (row)? tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra column that indicates which table it is:

```
SELECT "table1" which, id FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT "table2" which, id FROM table2
```

Now you can use `$end['which']` to know which table each row came from.

`which` isn't a column in the table itself. It's an alias for the literal string that's just in the query.

To get the results ordered alternating between the tables, you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT "table1" which, id FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "table2" which, id FROM table2
) x
ORDER BY id, which
```

Comment: I have reached my question limit and i have a necessary question. plz someone share my question.
my question: **i used UNION ALL and want to my result be mixed up from two table. indeed i want first row of result be from table1 and second row be from table2**
anybody can help me ?! Tnx beforehand

Comment: I've added how to do that.

Comment: @Barmar tnx, but  the result of this code isn't alternatin, this code echo in first all rows of the table with shorter name and then echo rows of another table. This kind of sort isn't proper. You shouldn't order by name of table.
i want someting like this: (focus on output order)
when i use:
`SELECT * FROM table1 where culumn1='anything'`
and echo id, for example output is: 2,4,6 . 

when i use:
`SELECT * FROM table2 where culumn1='anything'`
and echo id, for example output is: 5,6,7 . 

now how use UNION ALL and ORDER BY to sorting output like this:
2,5,4,6,6,7

Comment: @Barmar can't help me ?

Comment: I had the columns backwards in the ORDER BY clause. Try it now.

Comment: It gets better, but not perfect. there is the best way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670500/how-the-results-get-mixed-between-two-tables-when-use-union

Comment: Yeah, my answer assumed that both tables have sequential IDs.

Comment: just something: using @variable in SQL code is optimized?  performance and speed are good ?  speed is so important for me

Comment: Not sure. Compare the results of EXPLAIN of the queries with and without it.

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT id as table1_id FROM table1 
                        UNION ALL SELECT id FROM table2;" , $link);
```

And then:

```
echo $end['table1_id'];
echo $end['id'];
```

Comment: This won't work. The column names in a union always come from the first sub-query.

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you, I am leaving my answer like this, so others can know about it