# How the results get mixed between two tables when use UNION

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to used UNION to SELECT two table in one query. Then I want to my result get mixed from two table (ordering alternating). Indeed I want first row of result be from `table1` and second row be from `table2`, like this (focus on output order):

When I use only:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE column1 = 'anything'
```

then echo id, my output is for example: **2,4,6**

When I use only:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 
WHERE column1 = 'anything'
```

then echo id, my output is for example: **5,6,7**

Now how use UNION and ORDER BY to sorting output like this : **2,5,4,6,6,7**

Comment: Which dbms? Besides, you need UNION ALL to keep both 6's.

Comment: what is 'dbms? you right, i should use UNION ALL to keep both 6's. tnx

Comment: Dbms, the database product you're using!

Comment: DBMS - Database Management System. Google it :)

Comment: I use mysql (phpmyadmin)

Comment: There's a pretty neat way to do this using window functions, but they are not available in MySQL. Probably the same result could be achieved by using `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Comment: What if the number of returned rows aren't the same? Do you want to continue with one table, or quit returning?

Comment: @jarlh, i want this:
output1: 2,4,6
output2: 5,6,7,8,9

result: 2,5,4,6,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alternate rows from the results of a union, you'll need to give each of them a rank that increases by two - one for odds, one for evens.

```
select @rank := @rank + 2 `rank`, *
  from table1, (select @rank := -1) q
    where column1 = 'anything'
union all
select @rank2 := @rank2 + 2 `rank`, *
  from table2, (select @rank2 := 0) q
    where column1 = 'anything'
order by rank asc;
```

sqlfiddle looks to be down else i'd create a demo, but it should work.

`@rank` and `@rank2` are variables. `@rank2 := @rank2 + 2` increments `@rank` by `2` for every row in the result set, and includes the new value in the results.
`from table2, (select @rank2 := 0) q` is just a way to force the variable to be initialised to `0` without having to run additional queries.  By starting the rank counter at `-1` for the first query, and `-0` for the second query, each row in the first query receives a rank in the sequence `1,3,5,7,...`, and every row in the second query receives a rank in the sequence `2,4,6,8,...`

**example**

```
mysql> create table table1 (id integer primary key auto_increment, column1 varchar(25));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> create table table2 (id integer primary key auto_increment, column1 varchar(25));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into table1 (column1) values ('abcd'), ('lmno'), ('abcd'), ('lmno'), ('pqr');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into table2 (column1) values ('lmno'), ('abcd'), ('abcd'), ('lmno'), ('abcd'), ('abcd'), ('abcd');
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

and the data:

```
mysql> select * from table1;
+----+---------+
| id | column1 |
+----+---------+
|  1 | abcd    |
|  2 | lmno    |
|  3 | abcd    |
|  4 | lmno    |
|  5 | pqr     |
+----+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table2;
+----+---------+
| id | column1 |
+----+---------+
|  1 | lmno    |
|  2 | abcd    |
|  3 | abcd    |
|  4 | lmno    |
|  5 | abcd    |
|  6 | abcd    |
|  7 | abcd    |
+----+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and the result:

```
mysql> select @rank := @rank + 2 `rank`, id from table1, (select @rank := -1) q where column1 = 'abcd' union select @rank2 := @rank2 + 2 `rank`, id from table2, (select @rank2 := 0) q where column1 = 'abcd' order by rank asc;
+------+----+
| rank | id |
+------+----+
|    1 |  1 |
|    2 |  2 |
|    3 |  3 |
|    4 |  3 |
|    6 |  5 |
|    8 |  6 |
|   10 |  7 |
+------+----+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: your idea is good, but id don't know sql very well, then i can't implement this. what is @ ? what is := ? :) !! i'm bginner.
anyway tnx alot

Comment: @Fatemeh i just pasted some example output as well

Comment: @Fatemeh `@rank` is a variable, `:=` assigns to the variable. so for every row, `@rank := @rank + 2` gets executed, and the value of rank increases. additional explanation added to the answer

Comment: WOW, YOU ARE PERFECT !!!!!
I do it and work correctly. Tnx alot ....
I have been involved this problem for one week !!!!

Comment: Mr pala all thing is Ok, just can you tell me:  
1. if i have 3 table, what  parameter should get change ?  
2. what is mean of (select @rank2 := 0) q

Comment: i explained that one in the answer -- it simply initialises the variable so we can use it without having to create more queries. if you add another table in the exact same way, you need to initialise the variable to `-2`, and change all the increments from `2` to `3`.

Comment: ow, got it. tnx pal ..!